# recognizing the end of video in vimeo embed player in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, vimeo

I am using vimeo embed iframe code to play videos in my ipad app.

```
<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/ 27127177?title=1&byline=0&portrait=1&loop=1' width='600' height='600' frameborder='10' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>>
```

after the video is completed vimeo is showing a list of videos related to that user or related to that video, and if the user presses on them the control is changing to Vimeo website, is there a way to detect the end of video from web view so that i can stop loading the list of videos.